# How to set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER variable in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, mingw

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auwL0.png)

Does anyone know where the variable CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER is defined. I configured c_cpp_properties.json in vscode, but it doesn't seem to take effect.

Comment: can you please share your CMakeLists.txt file contents

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the description of `cmake.configureSettings` on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md